# Can't create virtual device on Android Studio on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new on Android Studio and don't know much. I am using on Windows. I am unable to create virtual device through AVD manager, every time I create it gives this message:

> An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you always need virtualization for android emulator I guess
without virtualization how will you create an abstract environment to support android kernel and its features?

[emulator details](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html)